# Solve the initial value problem $y' = \frac{xy^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ with $y(0)=-1$

Tags: calculus, integration, initial-value-problems

> Solve the initial value problem $y' = \frac{xy^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ with
>   $y(0)=-1$

I'd like to know if my solution is correct. To keep it short, just assume that all integration steps I did are right.

The differential equation isn't in its standard form $y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$, so we bring it to that form:

$$y'-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}y^3=0$$

And at this step is my first doubt; is it really the standard form? It doesn't have to be $y$ instead of $y^3$?

Continuing, the integration factor is $e^{\int{P(x)dx}}=e^{\int{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}dx}=e^{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, in next step we will multiply the differential equation with $\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

$$\Rightarrow  \frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}y^3=0 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{1+x^2} \cdot\frac{dy}{dx}- \sqrt{1+x^2} \cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}y^3=0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{1+x^2} \cdot y)-x \cdot y^3=0 \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \int{\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{1+x^2} \cdot y)-x \cdot y^3} = \int{0} \text{ }dx \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{1+x^2} \cdot y = c \Leftrightarrow y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}c$$

We know that $y(0)=-1 \Leftrightarrow -1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+0^2}}c \Leftrightarrow c=-1$

$\Rightarrow y = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making it yourself way too hard here.

We have

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{xy^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

or equivalently:

$$\frac{dy}{y^3} = \frac{xdx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Now integrate both sides, to obtain:

$$\frac{-1}{2y^2} = \sqrt{1+x^2} + c$$

Now solve for $y$ and fill in the initial values.

Comment: I continued, is it alright? Too bad there is a negative sign inside the root.. $$-\frac{1}{2y^2}=\sqrt{1+x^2}+c \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{y^2} = -2(\sqrt{1+x^2}+c) \Leftrightarrow y^2=\frac{1}{-2(\sqrt{1+x^2}+c)} \Leftrightarrow (-1)^2 = \frac{1}{-2(\sqrt{1+0^2}+c)} \Leftrightarrow 1 = \frac{1}{-2(1+c)} \Leftrightarrow 1 = -2(1+c) \Leftrightarrow -\frac{1}{2} = 1+c \Leftrightarrow c=-\frac{3}{2}$$ 

now we insert c: $$y^2=\frac{1}{-2(\sqrt{1+x^2}-\frac{3}{2})} \Leftrightarrow y^2=\frac{1}{-2\sqrt{1+x^2}+3} \Leftrightarrow y = ^{+}_{-}\sqrt{\frac{1}{-2\sqrt{1+x^2}+3}}$$

Comment: Looks good. Be careful with equivalence arrows though. When you start inserting the initial values it should be $\Rightarrow$ instead of $\iff$. Preferably, also, I would write the answer in the form $y^2 = \dots$ but this is just a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks so much! :D